# Easy lightweight pop3 server

Tags: linux, pop3

I'm writing a POP3 proxy, and would like a simple, quick-to-setup POP3 server to do some local testing.

Is there a lightweight POP3 server, that I can easily configure with an account and some fake e-mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHCS has this capability. I am assuming you are using ubuntu. You can check this thread in ubuntu forums [Pop 3 mail server](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=23702)

Comment: Wow, Gandalf's setup script appears to install VHCS stuff into Apache too. That wouldn't be my idea of a `lightweight POP3 server`. :)

Comment: Thanks and some more characters